# How to disable CapsLock pop-up message

Tags: keyboard, logitech-keyboard

I got the below annoying pop-up when I press <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> (and similarly <kbd>NumLock</kbd>). How can I get rid of it? Is it a Windows feature or an app?

[image]

Comment: It normally goes away in a second, so most people just ignore it. Otherwise, find the Hotkey program / driver on your computer and install that. I have something similar on my Lenovo ThinkPad so it is a Vendor / Manufacturer offering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, it was not a Windows feature. I turned it off in Logitech Options.
[image]